# How to have fusioncharts time marker mouse click event keep tooltip open

Tags: fusioncharts

I'd like to be able to trigger a mouse click event on this: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/fusiontime-component/time-marker so that the tooltip does not close.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As of now FusionCharts do not have support for triggering `timeMarkerClick` or `timeMarkerRollover` event to keep the tool-tip of the time marker open without any actual `timeMarkerClick` or `timeMarkerRollover` action over it.

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts do not have support for triggering to keep the tool-tip open.

**timeMarkerClick** event is fired when a user clicks on a time instant marker’s box or a time span marker’s rectangular area.

```
     "events": {
   "timeMarkerClick": function(ev) {
     console.log(ev);
   }
 }
```

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/api/fusiontime-events#timemarkerclick

Here is a demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/01fxks5q/1/